# Linear actuator suggestion - fast , powerful and small

Tags: dc-motor, linear, actuator

Suggestion for linear actuators?
Some desired specs

- Very fast [coompletes forward motion in 10-20 ms
- Just a pulse reaction needed - Can move forward with great speed
- Backward thrust not needed; can be done manually
- Power available: 12 V, 1 A or similar
- Can be electrically triggered actuators
- Small [About 1/4th of hand]

Suggestions are welcome on DIYs and products.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more specs? how much mass (additional to the actuator) is to be moved - alternately how much force is needed? how much power is available (V&A)? how often is that movement going to take place? should the back-stroke be just as fast as the forward action? Are answers to be confined to electrical actuators, or can they be only electrically triggered?

Comment: I would guess with the speed requirement you are limited to voice coil linear actuators: http://moticont.com/voice-coil-motor.htm

Comment: @bukwyrm I have added most of the specs asked!

Comment: What distance should it move?

Comment: Basic physics begs the questions; what is F=ma and E= 1/2 mv2= VI*t. ? In your specs!!

Answer (score 1):

look into CO2 capsules, and the electric valves from softair-pistols (because they are geared towards the pressures encountered with those capsules, and they run on electrics with 9-14V) plus a small pneumatic cylinder (if you go with full pressure, those will act faster than you specced, but if you use the internals from a softair, the input is adjustable)